# How to zoom bar chart on hover of a bar in carbondesignsystem simple-bar-chart with Angular13?

Tags: angular, carbon-design-system

I have  component. I want to zoom the particular bar on hover.

```
<ibm-simple-bar-chart
[data]="data"
[options]="options"
#ref>
</ibm-simple-bar-chart>
```

@ViewChild('ref', {static: false})
public barChart: any;

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if(this.barChart) {
    this.barChart.chart.services.events.addEventListener('bar-mouseover', 
      (e: any) => {
      console.log('Hover event')'
     });
  }
}
```

I tried the above option. But couln't figure out how to proceed further.

Do we have any other option to do this?